# unit тестирование

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, testng

Как бы Вы протестировали данный метод?

```
public boolean addStudent(Student student, Group group) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    // DaoUtil daoUtil = new DaoUtil();
    PreparedStatement statement = getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT  INTO  student(idstudent,firstname, secondname, idgroup) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    statement.setInt(1, student.getStudentId());
    statement.setString(2, student.getName());
    statement.setString(3, student.getSurName());
    statement.setInt(4, group.getGroupId());
    statement.executeUpdate();
    getConnection().close();
    return true;
}
```

Метод getConnection добавлен статическим импортом и осуществляет конект к базе данных, метод выполняет запись данных в базу

Comment: А что именно вы тут хотите тестировать? Все, что может сломаться, является внешними, по отношению к данному методу, объектами. Тестируйте их.

Comment: ну смотрите, у меня есть просто классы в которых соответственно только private поля и гетеры - сеттеры и конструктор, что я могу там протестировать? мне кажется ничего, разве сверять то что передал на set и тем что получит по get

Comment: Ну я бы и так и эдак протестировал бы. Но в основном используя код и junit

Comment: у меня задание написать тесты к моему приложению, вот я и не могу понять как это сделать, основной функционал это запись в базу каких то данных, студента, оценки, предмета, группы и это типичный метод среди них)

Comment: Смотрите, поломать этот метод изнутри можно только ошибившись в типе подставляемого аргумента (`return true` - это шедеврально, да) Как вариант - сделать тестовую БД, мок для `getConnection` и тестировать, что в нее записалось именно то, что должно было

Comment: у меня метод сразу имел чуть иной вид( в методе был конекшен) и когда конект не устанавливался возвращалось false, так как конект перенес блоки try catch return false, конект сделал общим и соответственно false убрал, а bool метод остался и тру также)

Comment: Выглядит как какое-то тестовое задание

Comment: не совсем) задание в академии IT компании, развиваем свою маленькую программу